# What is the difference between StoreModule.forRoot() and StoreModule.forFeature()

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

Recently ngrx store changed the way to register the store variables in an angular application.

What is the difference between StoreModule.forRoot() and StoreModule.forFeature()

Do we need to register both to make the application work?

Comment: read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f) about `forRoot` and `forChild` difference. It's the same here for `forRoot` and `forFeature`

Answer (score 40):

Its used with lazy loaded reducers. When you have (lazy loaded) feature modules and you want to register reducers within that module, then you use `forFeature`. Otherwise, in your `AppModule` you use `forRoot`.

Answer (score 24):

First of all, for dealing easily with Angular modules, you've to know some basic terminology that will help you with problems similar to this in the future.

An Angular app is (basically) made of a module, named "AppModule" that is conventionally known as **Root Module**: this is the main module of the application, the one bootstrapped in the *main.ts* file that is, actually, the application entry point. When you import some external modules into the *imports* array of the AppModule, you usually invoke the static method *forRoot* for giving an initial configuration to that module: it's the case of the StoreModule's forRoot method, which you set the store's initial configuration.

You can develop your application finding some "zone of concerns" to solve a specific part of your problem. When you merge components, directives, services and other Angular elements into a module, that module becomes a **feature module** because, as the naming convention suggests, it provides a feature to your application. Doesn't matter how you load a module (Eagerly or Lazily), it will always be a feature module.

Now, maybe, you've already answered to your question by yourself:

1. The **forRoot** method is invoked in the AppModule and, generally, **once in the application** to initialize the Store and provide the initial reducers/actions/state configuration. If you use the EffectsModule, you'll invoke the forRoot method on this module too:

   @ngModule({
   imports: [
   StoreModule.forRoot(),
   EffectsModule.forRoot()
   ]
   })
   class AppModule {}
2. The **forFeature** method is invoked in any feature module that requires it's own part of the state management: as an example, an UserModule will define it's own portion of the state, describing the required actions, reducers and so on. If you use the EffectsModule, remember to invoke the forFeature method against it too. As you may have understood by yourself, *forFeature* (as the more generic Angular's *forChild* method) can be invoked multiple times for the same imported module in the application:

   AppModule -> StoreModule.forRoot(...)
   UsersModule -> StoreModule.forFeature(...)
   OtherModule -> StoreModule.forFeature(...)

Finally, remember that the forRoot and the forFeature signatures are slightly different from each other: the latter has, in fact, the first parameter that describes the *feature name*. The other parameters, if I can recall properly, are the same as the forRoot method. If you try generating a boilerplate for a feature module with the @ngrx/schematics package with the following command:

```
ng generate feature user/User -m modules/users/users.module.ts --group
```

You will find that the *feature name* will simply be the lowercased version of the **User** word in the given command: *user*.

Answer (score 13):

Always Import forRoot() calls
I think this is probably pretty obvious, but just for the record, you’ll need to make sure you’ve already imported the root store and effects module in your main application.

```
imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    ...
```

If you have reducers or effects that apply at this level, you should add them in here, but even if you don’t have any reducers or effects at the root level of your application, you need to make these two calls.  Otherwise, the forFeature() calls won’t be able to access the root store or effect location to add in the reducers and effects for the feature.

Answer (score 2):

In angular project's you can use [Feature modules](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules) to partition the app into focused areas, so it is natural to put the store of that feature in its own module using `StoreModule.forFeature()` and then import the module in the main app module. you should remember  that the main module should have `StoreModule.forRoot()` even if you have modularized your entire application you  should use `StoreModule.forRoot({})` with an empty object so when you import the feature module it will attach the state of that module to your state.

note: lazy loaded modules are a kind of feature module so you can use  `StoreModule.forFeature()`  to set up the state for that part of the application.

Comment: Alas, for NgxsModule it does not work like that... even though would be great...